# Backing up recursively is not copying directories

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have the following line in a script to backup and it is not recursively copying all the directories, it gets the files but just lumps them all together. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

```
find . -type f -not -executable -exec cp -ruv {} /run/media/user/32GB/prog/ \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-exec` argument to find simply executes that command on each item returned. So, for example, if you have a directory set like:

```
>$ find .
.
./a.txt
./b.txt
./dir1
./dir1/c.txt 
./dir2
./dir2/d.txt
```

The `-exec` portion will be run once for each line, substituting the text for `{}`.
So, in your case, it would recursively copy each entry to the specified directory.

```
cp -ruv a.txt /run/media/user/32GB/prog/
cp -ruv b.txt /run/media/user/32GB/prog/
cp -ruv dir1 /run/media/user/32GB/prog/
cp -ruv dir1/c.txt /run/media/user/32GB/prog/
etc, etc
```

Incidentally, you also mark `-not -executable`. This makes the real difference. Directories in Linux are executable. (The execute bit on directories manages permissions to list the contents of the directory, since folders can't be executed.)

```
>$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r--.   1 user user     1583 Feb 10 13:14 a.txt
-rw-rw-r--.   1 user user     1583 Feb 10 13:14 b.txt
drwxr-xr-x.   2 user user     4096 Nov 22  2013 dir1
drwxr-xr-x.   2 user user     4096 Nov 22  2013 dir2
```

So,

```
>$ find . -not -executable 
a.txt
b.txt
dir1/c.txt
dir2/d.txt
```

Won't return any directories, just a list of non-executable files (`-type f`). And, as it was told, `cp` copies each and every one of them, individually (since only directories can be copied recursively) to `/run/media/user/32GB/prog/`

A potential solution is to copy everything first, then do a `find`/`rm`

```
>$ cp -ruv . /run/media/user/32GB/prog/
>$ find /run/media/user/32GB/prog -executable -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Or a nasty `rsync` (I love `rsync`):

```
>$ find . -type f -not -executable > /tmp/filelist
>$ rsync -r --include-from=/tmp/filelist . /run/media/user/32GB/prog/
```

rsync will copy the current directory recursively, adding only the files specified - the non-exec ones. That will prevent the extra write/delete.

Comment: This is not fun.

What I am trying to do is recursively copy all non-executable files. How do I do this? The executables do not have an extension.

Comment: Copy, then use find to remove the executable files. I added it in my solution.

Comment: I did consider this, but it seems...silly to go through the unnecessary copying, removing.

Comment: I added another way, using rsync, which will skip the copy/remove

Comment: rsync is an absolute dream for backup. Use -a for archiving - making exact copies.

Comment: I'm backing up to a fat32 usb, so I can't use -a

Comment: rsync's `-a` is shorthand for `-rlptgoD`, so you could just drop the flags that are not supported on fat32 (am I correct that only `-r` works on fat32??)

Comment: Yeah, just the recursion (-r). Others are *nix attribs. And with this particular find/rsync implementation, recursive shouldn't be needed. Shouldn't do anything. Doesn't mean it **won't**, mind you, but it _shouldn't_ make a difference.